# Can SCHED_FIFO be preempted by SCHED_DEADLINE?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, real-time

As stated in the man pages:

```
A SCHED_FIFO thread runs until either it is blocked by an I/O
request, it is preempted by a higher priority thread, or it calls
sched_yield(2).
```

From the same source:

```
SCHED_DEADLINE threads are the
highest priority (user controllable) threads in the system; if any
SCHED_DEADLINE thread is runnable, it will preempt any thread
scheduled under one of the other policies.
```

Does that mean even threads with *rtprio* 99 will be preempted by a SCHED_DEADLINE thread? It's kinda directly stated there, but I'm a bit confused since I thought rtprio 99 would be the highest priority in the system (watchdogs, migration, posixcputimer...). I'd be interested to know this for both the standard kernel and the rt_patched one. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manpage is correct.  It should not be hard to find confirmation of this.

https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/linux/sched/deadline.h#n5?h=v4.10

> ```
> /*
>  * SCHED_DEADLINE tasks has negative priorities, reflecting
>  * the fact that any of them has higher prio than RT and
>  * NORMAL/BATCH tasks.
>  */
>
> #define MAX_DL_PRIO       0
> ```

This was the approach chosen by maintainer of the Linux scheduler.  I have quoted LWN's explanation below, although you should aspire to read the whole of any LWN article which becomes relevant to your interests.  As these are finite in length, I can't guarantee they resolve every specific confusion you might have.  https://lwn.net/Articles/356576/

> Peter Zijlstra, though, thinks that deadline scheduling should run at the highest priority; otherwise it cannot ensure that the deadlines will be met.

---

> I'm a bit confused since I thought rtprio 99 would be the highest priority in the system (watchdogs, migration, posixcputimer...)

LWN links to Peter's [initial review](https://lwn.net/Articles/356587/), which mentions this.

> The only two tasks that need to be the absolute highest priority are
>   kstopmachine and migrate, so those would need to be lifted above EDF,
>   the rest is not important :-)

I don't know exactly what migrate would be this context, but the LWN article does call out SMP realtime as being a challenge.

stopmachine is on the list that says "so don't do that for RT!", for this reason.  Peter makes this explicit [later on](https://www.spinics.net/lists/kernel/msg941510.html).

Watchdogs surely operate on greater timescales than realtime processes, and deadline scheduling will leave time for them to run later (see below).

Ironically, I'm struggling to find information on the behaviour of timers in the real-time kernel.  There's an [RT wiki](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/High_resolution_timers) which mentions this for priorities, but not deadlines... note the page was last edited 2008 and specifies a test machine with a PIII 400 Mhz cpu.  It's also interesting that Peter didn't mention timers in the initial review.  It does look like RT processes have been encouraged to use clock_nanosleep() if possible.  (Clearly this would have little or no utility for the CPUTIME clocks, which might be what you're referring to).

---

The deadline scheduler has the potential to guarantee that deadlines will be met, provided processes do not exceed their specified Worst Case Execution Time.  The priority scheduler does not have this feature.

The maintainers favoured this guarantee, rather than making it conditional on whether a SCHED_FIFO process is present.  Deadline scheduling without the guarantee would be rather different beast... whether or not that would have some utility remaining; I don't really know.

Deadline scheduled processes have a maximum bandwidth - which is enforced by the Linux scheduler.  In principle, it should be possible to look at the total bandwidth of deadline scheduled processes, as well as the largest execution period, and determine the worst-case effect on any priority scheduled processes.  The reverse would not be true, because there is no enforcement of WCET for the POSIX scheduling class SCHED_FIFO.

> A deadline system does away with static priorities. Instead, each running task provides a set of three scheduling parameters:
>
> - A deadline - when the work must be completed.
> - An execution period - how often the work must be performed.
> - The worst-case execution time (WCET) - the maximum amount of CPU time which will be required to get the work done.
>
> The "bandwidth" requirement of a process - what percentage of a CPU it needs - is easily calculated, so the scheduler knows at the outset whether the system is oversubscribed or not. The scheduler can (and should) refuse to accept tasks which would require more bandwidth than the system has available. By refusing excess work, the scheduler will always be able to provide the requisite CPU time to every process within the specified deadline. That kind of promise makes realtime developers happy.

Comment: Hej (: thanks a lot. I've been reading whatever I find about the SCHED_DEADLINE policy, for example [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-deadline.txt). But I hadn't found an _explicit_ confirmation. In [the article you mention](https://lwn.net/Articles/356576/) it is stated: "He repeated that SCHED_DEADLINE _**will probably**_ be placed above SCHED_FIFO in priority". It was written in 2009 so it might be so now, but I still don't know 100% sure ;) I'll assume it is though. Thanks for providing me with some more reading material and a nice answer. Cheers

Comment: Answer edited - I found something I could cite in the current kernel version (after looking at what one version of the patch(es) changed in the existing files).

Comment: (:  I guess you're right that it was not exactly confirmation. Manpage style can be [terribly terse](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/UnboundRatelimitDocsGotcha), so I read it as a pretty direct statement. (Which is unlikely to be out of date, because I knew SCHED_DEADLINE was added after SCHED_FIFO / SCHED_RR). That left me with one doubt I could express - why? - and that's what the LWN article provided.  (Which I recommend even old ones of, because they're quality and not all that long).

Comment: Hehe :P I just found the exact same header file! _.../linux/sched/deadline.h_ ain't it? (At least in my distro). Anyway, that is a very direct statement. Thanks once again.